# xmlHTTPRequest POST not sending data

Tags: php, mysql, post, xmlhttprequest

I had xmlHTTPrequest GET script which was working fine, but because of server issues I had to change it to POST method. I am unable to get the data in $_POST variable. When I checked in CHROME INSPECTOR debug tool, GET Method status is 200 ok. Need help to see if the javascript is correct.

xmlHTTPrequest file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showprodes(str2)
        {
        var q2 = encodeURIComponent(str2);
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          var url = "http://www.amg.in/amogtst/rateprod.php";
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
        xmlhttp.send(q2);
         }


    </script>

    <?

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT Prod_desc FROM PRODMAST ORDER BY Prod_desc");

        echo "<form name='f1'>";

        echo " <span class='style3'>Gas Type &nbsp;</span> <select name='Proddesc' onchange=\"showprodes(this.value);\"><option value=0>Select a Product</option>";
        while($nt2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
        echo "<option value='$nt2[Prod_desc]'>$nt2[Prod_desc]</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";// Closing of list box

            echo "</form>";
    ?>
```

Second script which updates the table as per the user selection from first php: rateprod.php file:

```
<?php
$q=$_POST['q2'];
$q2=mysql_real_escape_string($q);

include_once 'db.php';

mysql_query("UPDATE RATEMASTER_draft SET Prod_desc='$q2'");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your AJAX code, you aren't supplying the POST variables correctly. The format for the POST string being given to `xmlhttp.send()` needs to be in the same format as a GET string. Trying using `xmlhttp.send("q2=" + q2)`.

BTW, for future reference, you can use `print_r($_POST)` to show the contents of all POST variables. This can be very handy for debugging.

Comment: For POST'ing multiple variables, you could use something like: `xmlhttp.send("q2=" + q2 + "&q3=" + q3)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working fine now. I am trying to get this issue resolved from yesterday on stackoverflow, but none were able to give such a simple answer, you have made my day. Kudos mike!

Comment: You MUST not have them URL encoded. You can also send multipart form data.